# How do I tell npm I've updated my version of nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using Ubuntu, and the latest version of node that I can install with apt-get is 0.7. I downloaded 0.10 linux binaries from the node website and installed them in a hackish way (being a noob), but I couldn't manage to install npm, so I sudo-apt installed npm. However, even those when I run node -v the correct version appears, when I try to install a program with npm install, it tells me my version of node is 0.7 (which is too old to install the packages I want). How do I tell npm I'm running a newer version of node?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try uninstalling npm `sudo apt-get remove npm` and uninstalling node 0.7, then install npm back again. Also, make sure that node 0.10 is in /usr/bin/node. Also, in the future, consider using [nodeenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nodeenv/0.6.0)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't have to remove npm but I did have to place it in the /bin folder. Previously it was in the /usr/bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't have to reinstall npm, but had to move node to from /bin to /usr/bin.

Answer (score 0):

You should install node via apt-get (but first uninstall it just to make sure)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

From:
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager